# Kernel 3.3.2-6.fc16.x86_64 broadcom wireless not appearing

Tags: linux, wifi, broadcom

I'm using kernel 3.3.2-6.fc16.x86_64 and I have a Broadcom 4312.

When I run `iwconfig`, I get the following:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
p2p1      no wireless extensions.
```

I cannot use wireless, I have to use cable. How can I get my wireless network adapter up and running?

Comment: did you have wireless working previously on this computer?  previously on Fedora 16?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting with one of the older kernels?

When you boot, fedora gives you the option of booting from a few prior kernels.

If wireless works from a prior kernel, you can then wait for another kernel update and see if wireless works with that kernel.

Comment: how to boot with an older kernel, because on grub boot, i see only 3.3

Comment: on my machine I have these available:3.3.2-6.fc16.x86_64 , 3.3.2-1.fc16.x86_64 , 3.3.1-5.fc16.x86_64 . They are all 3.3 also.

Comment: What Fedora does is to keep older kernels (by default 3). If you just installed, you'll only see one.

Answer (score 0):

Some changes happened recently with these drivers. Try to put the firmware `bcm43xx-0.fw`  in`/lib/firmware/brcm`, if they are not already present there (maybe using symlinks). Try then `modprobe brcmsmac`.

Or you may wait for the next system update, which hopefully will fix the mess by itself.